# Documenter.jl: ignore docstring

Tags: julia, documentation

Using [Documenter.jl](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/), I keep getting these warnings:

```
┌ Warning: 60 docstrings not included in the manual:
│ 
│     ProtoSyn.Calculators.TorchANI.r_xml_travel! :: Union{Tuple{T}, Tuple{Union{LightXML.XMLDocument, LightXML.XMLElement}, String, Vector{T}}} where T<:AbstractFloat
│     ProtoSyn.Clustering.dunn_index :: Union{Tuple{T}, Tuple{Vector{T}, Matrix{T}}} where T<:AbstractFloat
│     ProtoSyn.Calculators.get_available_energy_function_components :: Tuple{Module}
│     Base.resize! :: Tuple{ProtoSyn.Calculators.VerletList, Int64}
│     ProtoSyn.Common
(...)
```

I want to ignore some (most) of these docstrings (they exist in the code base but I do not want to export them to the final documentation website). How can I ignore individual docstrings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try suppressing such warnings by specifying the `checkdocs` keyword option when calling `makedocs()`. Using `checkdocs=:exports` complains only if the unused docstring's function is exported. If you use `checkdocs=:none` in makedocs that should cause `makedocs` to ignore the unused docstrings. You might lose some error warnings for malformed docstrings though.